# MYSQL SELECT DISTINCT RECORDS GROUPED

Tags: mysql, select, group-by, distinct

**I need to select "four distinct random records" from specific four categories and then order by ascending.**

I tried to select sixteen random records and then I have grouped them by category_id

**Query:**

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT 
        id, 
        category_id, 
        description, 
        RAND() AS rnd
    FROM questions
    ORDER BY rnd
    LIMIT 16
) AS temp
GROUP BY temp.category_id
LIMIT 4
```

**Results in some moment :**

```
id      category_id     description     rnd
--------------------------------------------------------------
224         1           Question 7      0.004305024635330797
293         2           Question 10     0.006966075866451558
601         3           Question 2      0.001877430828174046
958         4           Question 54     0.0065207639769844375
```

**Results in other moment :**

```
id      category_id     description     rnd
--------------------------------------------------------------
230         1           Question 2      0.01622675640157122
310         2           Question 21     0.005430353810480194
159         4           Question 17     0.021778853630441106
```

The problem is that not always show the four categories
I need to fix this query, up to now I can't find the real solution. 
I need your help ! 
Thanks in advance !

Comment: current data and expected result will be much better

Comment: My data is equal exactly :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is to choose the categories *first* and then go back to the original data:

```
select q.*
from (select category_id, substring_index(group_concat(id order by rand()), ',', 1) as id
      from questions
      group by category_id
      order by rand()
      limit 4
     ) c4 join
     questions q
     on q.id = c4.id
order by category_id
```

There are other ways to do this, such as by using a bunch of `union all` statements.  But this is general and makes it easy to change the number of categories.

Comment: Great this is what I was looking for !

Here my SQL Fiddle with your solution [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b5c49/2/0)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I have other small question :)
How can I show more records but keeping the same logic?
for example 8, 16 and more